# Capture images/documents from Digital Camera/Scanner devices in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery,Is there any possible to capture images/scanned documents from  digital Camera/Scanner Connected to computer ?.These devices are connected through USB Port only.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming client-side, browser-based javascript, the simple answer is no, jQuery cannot, in itself, perform this task.

jQuery could conceivably be employed as part of a wider software application which performs such a task. The application would require significant other software to communicate with the device(s) and to serve data in such a way that it could be presented in the browser. I don't know of a capture application with this particular architecture but it is entirely possible that one might exist.

It is also possible that, in such an application, jQuery might be employed as part of a server role. In this case, we would be talking about Node.js, which (in a nutshell) uses ECMA-262 (javascript) as the application programming language for defining the behaviour of a server.